# LinkedIn API "Company Follow" how to Start follow a company

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, linkedin-api

Everyone,
I am implementing Linkedin API now. Most API request works fine. But I had met a problem for "Start Follow a company":

```
POST

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/following/companies
```

This is the request sample LinkedIn give, but there is no place to put id parameter, how to tell LinkedIn that which company I want to follow ?

I tried to use the similar one with Stop following, but it didnt work...

```
DELETE

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/following/companies/id={id}
```

Is any one know how to use it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-follow-and-suggestions), to get a list of companies the current user is following, you do:

```
GET
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/following/companies
```

To start following a company, you do:

```
POST
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/following/companies
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<company>
  <id>{id}</id>
</company>
```

To stop following you have it correct:

```
DELETE
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/following/companies/id={id}
```

You can play around with these on the [REST Console](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/rest-console/) to get familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the data with xml format, got the "bad request" response, and i modified to Json Format, it didn't work neither. Plus: I found out something strange: When I publish a post with data I have to use xml format, but if I want to like a post, I have to use a Json format, is there a rule for use which format?

Comment: Camellia - you should be able to use either format for posting. Your bad request response may be due to a bad OAuth header. Can you actually just do a simple get request and make it work.
I am a dev Advocate at linkedIn so if you put more of the debug information in your question it would be easier to help.

That said, Paul's answer is correct